# OneSignal - Send a notification from android app with a custom image from url

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, onesignal

I have a question: how can I customize a notification sent from my android app using onesignal with a custom image url?

I should send a notification like the image below:

[image: Notification]

It's all ok if I sent a basic notification without custom image url.
I composed this json in my android app to send the request to onesignal:

```
String strJsonBody = "{"
    + "\"app_id\": \"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx\","
    + "\"filters\": [{\"field\": \"tag\", \"key\": \"firestoreUserId\", \"relation\": \"=\", \"value\": \"" + notificationBundle.getPost().getUserId() + "\"}],"
    + "\"data\": {\"postId\": \"" + notificationBundle.getPost().getId() + "\"" +
                    ",\"postDescription\": \"" + notificationBundle.getPost().getDesc() + "\"},"
    + "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"Hey, " + notificationBundle.getUser().getFullName() + " notification\"}"
    + "}";
```

How the JSON above must be modified to add an image to notification?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `large_icon` as indicated in the [REST API docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-attachments).

Example: `large_icon:"https://website.com/path/to/resource.jpg"`