# OneSignal - Send a notification with a custom image from url (iOS)

Tags: ios, onesignal

I would like, via my app, to send a push notification to an iOS and Android app using OneSignal via an API call. I would like this notification to have a custom image.

As it is a user-chat application, I really would love to see the profile picture of the sender's message on the notification, when the end-user received a new message. Basically I would like to have a notification which would like the attached screenshot. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvXc3.png)

It seems that with Android it is quiet straightforward, indeed I've set the `large_icon` parameter as it is mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110017/onesignal-send-a-notification-from-android-app-with-a-custom-image-from-url), and it works fine.

But according to the docs, this is Android-only. Is there a similar way to do so with iOS ? If not, could you recommend an alternative way to handle it ?

Thanks in advance.